# How to perform a sql operation to all the fields which are not NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

| SAL | COMM | SAL + COMM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8000.00 | NULL | NULL |
| 16000.00 | 3000.00 | 19000.00 |
| 12500.00 | 5000.00 | 17500.00 |
| 29750.00 | NULL | NULL |
| 12500.00 | 14000.00 | 26500.00 |

Is it possible to have an expression like this

```
SELECT SAL, COMM, SAL + COMM
FROM EMPLOYEES
 WHERE IF COMM IS NOT NULL SET COMM = 0;
```

My Idea is IF COMM IS NULL then SAL + COMM := SAL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT SAL, COMM, SAL + COALESCE(COMM, 0)
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

This makes sense for your data.  It is not exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: You have typo in COALESDCE

Comment: I have found out that `IFNULL(COMM, 0)` also works.

Comment: @chrispin2510 . . . Except `COALESCE()` is a *standard* SQL function, not a bespoke function for a particular database.